# Ms Access queries equivalent in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access, migration

Queries in MS Access can act like views do in oracle in that you can query against them. Example: if you have a query in access called allProducts, you can also do

```
SELECT * from allProducts;
```

My questions is, what is the equivalent in Sql Server? I'm currently working on a project where we are converting all our ms access databases over to ms sql server. Tables get converted over to tables, but what about queries knowing very well our programmers used access queries as exampled above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A query in Access is a view in SQL Server. I am not sure whether the typical migration tools will bring those along and change them to views for you.

Be careful with the code you're using in your queries, as functions like FIRST(), IIF(), ISNULL() etc. either don't exist in SQL Server at all, or work differently.